# How can I get the light cover off my fixture?

Tags: bathroom, light

I have a light fixture in my bathroom and I’ve no idea how to remove the cover go replace the bulb, tried turning it, tried prying it off with no avail. There is a slight notch however trying to pry it off using this just isn’t happening.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance ,
Emma [image]

Comment: Some light fixtures are built with the intention that you never replace bulbs: you just disconnect and replace the entire fixture. Of course, those tend to be newer LED fixtures, so if one has failed already you should ask for your money back!

Answer (score 1):

There are fixtures now that screw in like a bulb over an keyless socket or similar. Turn the whole thing gently and see if it unscrews.

For example

[image: led fixture-bulb]

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Lightbulb-Replacement-Fixture-7-in-Round-White-60-Watt-Equivalent-Integrated-LED-Flushmount-Bright-White-54483142/205890895

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same fitting. Spent about 30 minutes trying to get off to change the bulb and thought I was going to pull the roof down!

A wide flat-head screw driver into the little notch, I was able to twist and pop it off! Success!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but instead of twisting the screwdriver, try simply tilting it upward and pulling slightly outward. You want to pry the light cover outward to get it over the ridge securing it to the base. You could also use a sharper tool to slip between the two easier.

Comment: Hello thanks for commenting, thing is trying to pull upward because of the ceiling being in the way yw difficult to do .....

Comment: Try something smaller, like a ten cent dime or the tab from a soda can. Or the back of a teaspoon or tablespoon measuring spoon, or really anything that's like a screwdriver but smaller.

Comment: A paint can tool might have the right hook, and is shorter.